# Return in __toString() with Escaping to HTML

Tags: php, escaping, tostring

I seem to have a problem with the method mentioned above:

```
    public function __toString()
    {
        ?>
        Some html code
        Some more html code
        <?=echo $this->content?>
        Last of the html code
        <?
        return '';
    }
```

I need it that in this method I can break PHP code, so I can better format and see the HTML code. But if I omit the return I get the exception:

> __toString() must return a string value.

Any way i can manage without the return?

Comment: First and foremost: **you shouldn't do it at all.** toString is not for markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following using [output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
public function __toString()
{
  ob_start() ;
    ?>

    Some html code
    Some more html code
    <?=echo $this->content?>
    Last of the html code

    <?php
   $content = ob_get_content() ;
   ob_end_clean() ;
    return $content ;
}
```

So, in fact you store your output in a buffer, put the content into a variable, clean the buffer.

After that you can successfully return the string and make your function work.

You cannot bypass the `return`, it is a `magic method`, and you have to implement it.

Comment: I had hoped i wouldn't need to use "ob" funcs. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Trust me, output buffer is a very useful thing. :)

Comment: @user2547316 you are right. Everything is useful but that doesn't mean that everything have to be used everywhere. Take a look at the Angiel's answer, the only sensible answer here

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the other answers may technically work, they are both an abuse of the __toString() method which is used to return a string representation of the object.

It sounds to me that you need a new method eg

```
public function outputHTML()
{
    ?>
    Some html code
    Some more html code
    <?=echo $this->content?>
    Last of the html code
    <?
}
```

which you then just call at the appropriate point by calling `$object->outputHTML()` rather than just calling `$object`

This is much easier to understand and will make maintaining your code much simpler in future as no one would realistically expect `__toString()` to print out a load of markup, text and then not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a use for the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
public function __toString() {
    $contents = <<<EOT

    <p>This is some text and you can still use $variables</p>

EOT;

    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: Y I NOT KNOW HOW MAKE INLINE LINK?? Thanks Chris.